# Is there a more elegant way to write this using Scalaz?

Tags: scala, scalaz

The code below works but pattern matching on Option b doesn't look elegant.
Is there a way to avoid it while keeping the same semantics?

```
object A {
  def apply(b: B): ValidationNEL[String, A] = ...
}

case class C(i: Int, a: Option[A])

object C {
  def apply(i: Int, b: Option[B]): ValidationNEL[String, C] = b match {
    case None => Success(C(i, None))
    case Some(sb) => A(sb).map(bb => C(i, Some(bb)))
  }     
}
```

Comment: 'elegant' is subjective . If you feel uncomfortable with pattern matching just say so but labeling as 'elegant' or not distracts. Just say so if you are simply looking for an alternative way to express the same construct

Comment: @AndreasScheinert: To some degree _elegant_ is defined by the community, and there's definitely a dispreference for pattern matching on `Option` among experienced Scala developers.

Comment: In this particular case there might be a majority who has this preference. I still don't like the term 'elegant' in conjunction with 'style'  but that maybe only me ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using scalaz, you can fold over Option

```
b fold ( sb => A(sb) map (bb => C(i, some(bb))), C(i, none).success)
```

There's probably a way of simplifying the `sb => A(sb) map (bb => C(i, some(bb)))` using *pointfree style* but this is often ugly in scala:

### Setup

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

object A {
  def apply(b: B): ValidationNEL[String, A] = sys.error("")
}
case class A()
case class B()
case class C(i: Int, a: Option[A])

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined module A
defined class A
defined class B
defined class C
```

### First impl

```
scala> def apply(i: Int, b: Option[B]): ValidationNEL[String, C] =
     | b fold ( sb => A(sb) map (bb => C(i, some(bb))), C(i, none).success)
apply: (i: Int, b: Option[B])scalaz.Scalaz.ValidationNEL[String,C]
```

### Second Impl

If you declare first-class functions, you stand a better chance of composition. For example:

```
object A { val fromB: B => ValidationNEL[String, A] = _ => sys.error("") }
object C { val fromA: Int => A => C = i => a => C(i, some(a)) }

defined module A
defined module C
```

Then

```
scala> def apply(i: Int, b: Option[B]): ValidationNEL[String, C] =
     | b fold (A.fromB andThen (_ map C.fromA(i)), C(i, none).success)
apply: (i: Int, b: Option[B])scalaz.Scalaz.ValidationNEL[String,C]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need scalaz specific stuff to simplify this, just use `Option.map`:

```
b.map { sb => /* will only be called if b is Some[A] */ }.getOrElse { /* will only be called if b is None */ }
```

I can't give you the exact solution, because the code you posted is not complete. The `A` in `case class C` is not in scope. Should this be a type parameter, or is there a `class A` belonging to the `object A`?

Comment: A `ValidationNEL` is a validation